# Sharing single file between gunicorn workers

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, gunicorn

I'm trying to create flask application with gunicorn. I defined number of gunicorn workers to (multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2) + 1 according to documentation.

There is problem beacuse in my flask application there is need to wrtite something to single file when HTTP request will come. If more than on worker will do it in the same time there are some errors in application.
Is it possible to define some Lock between gunicorn workers?